Upgrade from 5.65.1 to 5.74.0 - Error "Expected to find one Participant record, but there were zero." when registering for an event
I performed a Civi upgrade from v5.65.1 to 5.74.0 on Wordpress 6.5.4.
I am running Php 8.2.19.
I have also added.... define('CIVICRM_SMARTY_AUTOLOAD_PATH',
'/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/autoload.php');
into civicrm.settings.php
The upgrade was successful, however we are getting this error when registering for an event "Expected to find one Participant record, but there were zero."
Error log is as follows:-
[error]
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
"message" => "Expected to find one Participant record, but there were zero."
"code" => null
"exception" => CRM_Core_Exception {#13091
#message: "Expected to find one Participant record, but there were zero."
#code: 0
#file: "/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Array.php"
#line: 1245
#cause: null
-_trace: null
-errorData: array:1 [
"error_code" => 0
]
trace: {
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Array.php:1245 {
CRM_Utils_Array::single(iterable $items, string $recordTypeLabel = 'record')
› if ($result === NULL) {
›   throw new \CRM_Core_Exception("Expected to find one {$recordTypeLabel}, but there were zero.");
› }
}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/Result.php:90 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment.php:1245 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalImpl.php:258 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalImpl.php:897 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:1168 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Register.php:899 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:646 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php:153 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php:120 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:355 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:333 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1231 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.basepage.php:425 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:324 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:348 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php:565 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp.php:830 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php:1336 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/wp-blog-header.php:16 { …}
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/index.php:17 { …}
}
}
]
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Are you using Paypal Standard?

@Pradeep - We are using PayPal Express

It was a regression issue caused by a recent change.
I have submitted a PR for the fix and should be available in the next release. Alternatively, you can apply the patch

@ Pradeep - can you please provide more information on how I apply this patch. Do I copy this code into the file. thx

yes that's correct

I removed line 361 and  added the new line as per your line in the file PayPalImpl.php
$args['cancelURL'] = $this->getCancelUrl($params['qfKey'], ($params['participantID'] ?? NULL));
however I still got the same error.

Did you the same line?

Apply this patch https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/30392.patch

@Pradeep...yes  I did the same line.
I have reverted the first patch.
Question - Do I need both patches?

Nope, the latest one only.

it looks like the latest patch worked on my production server....hence I am very appreciative of your assistance.

The latest release contains the fix now

@Pradeep - as mentioned above we are not getting the error and PayPal payment goes thru and we do receive the funds. However we have noticed that the new registered participant is not being added to the event. When we look at the new participant record -in the Event tab -it shows that the participant has the status as "Pending (incomplete transaction)".  Could you pls suggest what we do here.

@PradeepNayak is this patch supposed to work for stripe checkout as well?

yes or you can upgrade to latest civi
